# Prove that if a real matrix $A$ is symmetric and $A^2=0$, then $A=0$

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, nilpotence

> Prove that if a real matrix $A$ is symmetric and $A^2=0$, then $A=0$.

Didn't really understand how a squared matrix could be equal to $0$.

Comment: $\|Ax\|^{2}=\langle Ax , Ax \rangle =\langle A^{2}x , x \rangle=0$

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry $(i, j)$ of $A^2$ can be written out as
$$
[A^2]_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik} A_{kj}
$$
Along the diagonal $(i=j)$ we can use that $A$ is symmetric, $A_{ik} = A_{ki}$, and simplify the formula above
$$
[A^2]_{ii} = \sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}^2.
$$
For the real-valued $A$ this is a sum of non-negative numbers meaning that if the sum is zero then all elements of the sum must also be zero.
$$
[A^2]_{ii} = 0 \Longrightarrow A_{ik} = A_{ki} = 0 \quad \forall k
$$
Using this and if the diagonal of $A^2$ is zero then we can prove that all elements of $A$ must also be zero (assuming, of course, that $A$ is symmetric).